# Render image that is linked

Tags: 8, theming, media, navigation

I am loading an unmananged image file and would like to render it in a block, but it should be linked.
I have an uri (public://...) and I am able to render the image using

$build['my_image'] = [
          '#theme' => 'image_style',
          '#style_name' => 'large',
          '#uri' => $uri,
];

This works, but how can I render it beeing linked to some url?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

image_formatter is to render an entity field, you can't use that without having that.

Try using a render array for the link, like this:

```
$type_link_nested_array = [
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => ['#theme' => 'image_style', '#style_name' => 'large', '#uri' => $uri, ],
  '#url' => Url::fromUri('https://www.drupal.org'),
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Without adding image styling (as original question never mentioned that), I found this to work:

```
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;
$img = '<img src="path_to_my_image" />';
$rendered_image = render($img);
$image_markup = Markup::create($rendered_image);
$link = Link::fromTextAndUrl($image_markup, Url::fromUri('internal:/my_link_path'))->toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably need to render the image yourself and then add the link around it. So something like:

```
$img_render_array =  [ '#theme' => 'image_style', '#style_name' => 'large', '#uri' => $uri, ];
$img = render($img_render_array)->__toString();
$build['my_image']['#markup'] = '<a href="/">'.$img.'</a>';
```

Comment: isn't there any possibilty using '#theme' => 'image_formatter' ? I don't know how to use it. The documentation says: Available variables:
 * - image: A collection of image data.
 * - image_style: An optional image style.
 * - url: An optional URL the image can be linked to.
However I don't understand what to pass as image.

Comment: Yes that would work by the looks of it. So in the test code it has:
     $base_element = array(
    '#theme' => 'image_formatter',
    '#image_style' => 'test',
    '#item' => $entity->image_test,
    '#url' => Url::fromUri('base:' . $path),
  );

With $entity->image_test being the image object from a field by the looks of it

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21src%21Tests%21ImageThemeFunctionTest.php/function/ImageThemeFunctionTest%3A%3AtestImageFormatterTheme/8.2.x

Comment: I don't have an entity and I don't want to use managed files. What do I need to pass as image/item ? I only have the uri to the image.