# How do you wrap an image with a link?

Tags: media

In Drupal 7 this was done with the l() command and setting the html option to true. I have found the Link::fromTextAndUrl() method in Drupal 8 but no mention of something similar to the html option.

[EDIT]
I think i was not clear with my original question. This is not for an image field; i was simply asking how to wrap a link around:

```
<img src="path_to_my_img">
```

Answer (score 2):

This way should be bulletproof:

```
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

$url = $node->get('field_url')->getValue();
$imageUri = $node->get('field_image')->entity->getFileUri();
$image = [
  '#theme' => 'image_style',
  '#style_name' => 'medium',
  '#uri' => $imageUri,
  '#width' => 200,
  '#height' => 100
];
$rendered = render($image)
$linkMarkup = Markup::create($rendered);
$link = Link::fromTextAndUrl($linkMarkup, $url);
$link = $link->toRenderable();
render($link)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Link::fromTextAndUrl() is the replacement for l(), but in D8 you use toRenderable() instead of a html option. This produces a render array which is rendered later.

```
use Drupal\Core\Link;

  $renderable = Link::fromTextAndUrl($title, $url)
    ->toRenderable();
```

BTW you can build this render array directly, with the same result, or the image as title, see [Render image that is linked](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/255010/render-image-that-is-linked/255027#255027)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;
$img = '<img src="path_to_my_image" />';
$rendered_image = render($img);
$image_markup = Markup::create($rendered_image);
$link = Link::fromTextAndUrl($image_markup, Url::fromUri('internal:/my_path'))->toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this functionality is preserved in D8

You could either do it in a **twig template** `node--[type-name].html.twig`

```
<a href="{{ content.field_url }}"> {{ content.field_image }} </a>
```

Or you could do it in a **custom module** manually

```
$url = $node->get('field_url')->getValue();
$image_uri = $node->field_image->entity->getFileUri();
$image_url = \Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle::load("large")->buildUrl($image_uri);
$image_with_link = "<a href='" . $url . "'>" . $image_url . "</a>";
```

Comment: I was looking for the replacement of the l() function; you have just typed out the html for an A tag.